# Jsoup href request and to output on file

Tags: java, http, httprequest, jsoup

I made this sample to request one url query through a java application. The request connection and query are right. But, I'm missing how am I able to get all href elements from the query and write on one output file? Anyone has any guidelines?

Thanks in advance

```
Document engineSearch=Jsoup.connect("http://ask.com/web?q="+URLEncoder.encode(query))
                                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)")
                                        .get();
            String title = engineSearch.title();
            Elements links = engineSearch.select("a[href]").first().getAllElements();

            String queryEncoding=engineSearch.outputSettings().charset().name();

        file = new File(folder.getPath()+"\\"+date+" "+Tag+".html");

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file),queryEncoding);
        writer.write(engineSearch.html());
        writer.close();
```

Comment: What you want to write into the `File`. Links or whole html file?  Whats the point in selecting `a[href]` elements when you are writing the whole html content to file?

Comment: My point is, I want to write the entire HTML file. I don't think that is possible but if it's I would like to write it inside one unique file. For example: Search on ask.com return 5 pages. I want from the search ask explore offline those 5 pages, one file - but if it's not possible I want one solution to simple download all a[href] (which means links from the website) and them store to explore offline // thanks for the help

Comment: What you want to do is after extracting the links, write code which will iterate through each of the links and download / save them on disk.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using websphinx to support what I want but I'm still working to give some feedback

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of exactly what you want, I dont have a dev environment handy but something along those lines should work

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = doc.select("a");

for (Element e : links) {
 String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
 String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/", which you can save to file
}
```

Comment: Ty for the support, but even though I'm still stucked.. =/